# Migrating from Parse to AWS Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-dynamodb, parse-server

I have been following this guide to migrate my existing Parse server into AWS using Dynamo DB as the database.

The guide covers using MongoDB as the database however I need to use DynamoDB. Can anyone provide information as to how I can do this, or any resources that guide this process?

Comment: MongoDB and DynamoDB are vastly different. I doubt parse server can use DynamoDB.

Comment: This might be helpful for data migration: https://calorious.wordpress.com/2016/02/22/episode-2-formatting-data-for-dynamodb/

Answer (score 1):

Work has begun on a [DatabaseAdapter](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/DatabaseAdapter.js) that will allow you to use a NoSQL database (such as DynamoDB) that is different from a MongoDB. You can find more information about the development [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/20).